how to get the difference between two dates in JPA criteriabuilder api?
Im trying to use criteria builder to get the difference between two dates in millisecond or smaller precision. I’m using H2, and for the life of me i cant do:
cb.function(“DATEDIFF”, BigInteger.class, cb.literal(“NANOSECOND”), …date1, date2)

However i get an error explaining that parameter 1 (the nanosecond literal) should be a temporal unit and not an object. Upon inspection, the nanosecond parameter is getting built in the sql surrounded with single quotes, when in sql it should be not surrounded by any quotes.
does anyone know how to implement this? i cant find any information online.

i see other people using builder.literal(“”) with no problems, so im very confused

Your pure Java would of course be Duration.between(instant1, instant2).toMillis();

@g00se forgot to mention, the second date is from the database so i can’t do pure java

Riiiiiight. I don't quite get that point. If it's half and half then both approaches are ... half and half. Aren't they? (iow fetching it from the db to do in pure Java)

not mentioned is that i want to group the entities by the a time interval that this time difference falls in and aggregate them via count and some type. Thats why i can’t just get all the entities from the database and then do the grouping/aggregation in java. I mean i guess i could but it would be way faster to just so it in jpa right?

Well personally I wouldn't know how to do that in JPA. Sounds quite tricky ;)

thanks for the comments btw. I have the other logic for the grouping and such worked out. I just need to take one date and subtract it by another, and i suppose thats an impossible task for jpa lmao. why is this so tricky!
